# Python OS module, deleting folders

Tags: python, cmd

hey guys why this line of code doesn't return anything. It's like it keeps running.... It deletes the file I want it to delete but the program does not exit.
`os.system('cmd /k rmdir /s /q {}'.format(path))`

Comment: I use this to delete all the contents of a directory, especially when it has hidden files in it. (E.g. .git file.)

Comment: Post a [minimal reproducible example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self%2Dcontained%20correct%20example.) so that we can see if something is blocking/looping in execution. In theory, `os.system` should block program execution until the command you are calling returns.

Comment: This code is inside a class method. If I don't call this, the program works flawlessly...

Comment: I've no idea why you'd need to run a built-in cmd.exe command line to do something which can be done without. Use `import shutil` along with `shutil.rmtree()`

Answer (score 2):

```
> cmd /?

/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

Try `/c` or just `os.system('<your code without cmd /c >')`.

This is because parameter `/k`(keep) let cmd remains while `/c`(close) not.

Comment: Thanks man, I think changing it to /c worked... appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

A call to `os.system` will return only an exit value. If it's stuck - it may be waiting for a file lock, like a cmd shell in that subdirectory or an open file.

I would suggest using subprocess.call (or check call) with `shell=True`, which would eliminate the wrapping cmd call.

However, I would take this one step further and suggest using the `shutil.rmtree` function to recursively delete a directory.

Comment: Actually, I used the shutil.rmtree before, but I don't think it deletes the hidden files inside the given directory...

Comment: Hmm - if the files arent already locked - I'm not sure it discriminates between hidden/non hidden.